# Laravel delay jobs aren't working with batch

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delay a job that gets added to a batch in my Laravel application, but it errors when trying to add a delayed job, what am I missing from my code?

```php
/**
 * Create chunked CSVs
 */
protected function createChunkedCSVs(Request $request)
{

    try {

      // get the CSV we stored
      $data = file($request->csv);

      // chunk the CSV into smaller csv's
      $chunks = array_chunk($data, 1000);

      // header and batch
      $header = [];
      $batch  = Bus::batch([])->dispatch();

      // latest form release
      $release = $this->getApplicationFormVersion();

      // begin chunking
      foreach ($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
        $data = array_map('str_getcsv', $chunk);

        if ($key === 0) {
          $header = $data[0];
          unset($data[0]);
        }

        $batch->add(new CustomersCsvProcess($data, $header, $release)->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)));
      }

      // return the batch
      return $batch;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: Try removing ->dispatch() from your $batch variable and then after your foreach, run $batch->dispatch();

Comment: I get a syntax error: `ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '-&gt;' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')' in file /Users/USER/Sites/PROJECT/app/Http/Controllers/CsvController.php on line 93`, as I'm adding delay to batch like: `$batch->add(new CustomersCsvProcess($data, $header, $release)->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)));`

Comment: @Devyn after a bit of tweaking, I get the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Bus\PendingBatch::add()` with `$batch->dispatch()->delay()` after my foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$batch->add(new CustomersCsvProcess($data, $header, $release)->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)));
```

to

```
$batch->add((new CustomersCsvProcess($data, $header, $release))->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)));
```